# Python Several problems of produce GIF by using animation.FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I encountered several problems when I was trying to produce a GIF by using animation function in Python.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import matplotlib.animation as animation

xdata = []
ydata = []
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(xdata, ydata, marker='o', markeredgewidth=9)
n = -1

def data_gen():
    global n
    while True:
        xdata.clear()
        ydata.clear()
        for i in range(3):
            xdata.append(random.randint(0, 10))
            ydata.append(random.randint(0, 10))
        n += 1
        print('The', n, 'generation')
        yield xdata, ydata

def init():
    plt.grid()
    line.set_linestyle('None')
    ax.set_xlim(0, 20)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 20)
    return line,

def animate(data):
    line.set_data(data)
    print('data', data)
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=animate, frames=data_gen, init_func=init, interval=200, blit=False)
ani.save('clear list.gif', writer='imagemagick')
plt.show()
```

**Problem 1**: There has been a pause (about 10 seconds) since the code started running, in the stage of 0–pause, the GIF can be saved, however, there is a black flash on saved GIF.

**Problem 2**: At the stage start–pause, I can not see the plot on the screen, after this pause, the plot appeared, the program goes into the normal stage.

**Problem 3**: I put the code `plt.grid()` in the function `init`. When the code is running, I cannot see grid on the plot, however, grid can be seen on the saved plot, why? If I add another code `plt.grid()` before the last code `plt.show()`, at this time, the grid will be shown on the plot.

Can someone tell me why this happens?

The code runs in:

- IDE: Pycharm 2019.3.4 Professional Edition
- Interpreter: Python 3.7
- OS:  Windows 10

Figure captured when the black shadow appears:

[image: Figure captured when the black shadow appears]

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, it seems to be working fine, maybe you can add more info about your environment, e.g. python version, OS, etc..

Comment: @Isma Hi, Isma, thanks for your reply, the code runs in Pycharm 2019.3.4 professional edition with interpreter Python 3.7, and the OS is windows 10.  
After the pause, the program goes into normal stage, I can also get the expected results, I am just very curious about this phenomenon.
Besides, even in the normal stage, there is no grid shown on the plot unless add the code 'plt.grid' before the last code.